# How to call a cb() inside promise().then() in async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async.js, waterfall

How to I call cb() in async.waterfall in inside the promise while calling  **.then**

Please have a look in below code

```
async.waterfall([
    function check_network(cb) {

        cb("ERROR-25", "foo")   //<<----- This works
    },    
    function process_pay(cb){    
        somePromise().then((status)=>{
            if(status){
                cb(null, status)  //<<----ERROR---- can't call cb() it looses the scope
            }
            cb("ERROR-26")  //<<--ERROR------ Same issse as above
        })
    },
    function print(cb){
        //some code
    } ])
```

Comment: "//<<----ERROR---- can't call cb() it looses the scope" — What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? You could, for example, replace `req.something()` and `process_pay` with mock functions using `setTimeout`

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: cb is not a function @Quentin

Comment: You should not not use `async.waterfall` at all when you are working with promises. But if you insist, then you definitely shouldn't call `cb` twice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Waterfall Function : The result values are passed as arguments, in order, to the next task.

Also first arguments in callback is reserved for Error. So when this line is executed

```
cb("ERROR-25")
```

That means an error is thrown. So next function will not be called.

Now coming to the question **'can't call cb() it looses the scope'**. In case **check_network** cb is called like below

```
cb(null, "value1");
```

The corresponding definition of **process_pay** should be as follows:

```
function process_pay(argument1, cb){    
    somePromise().then((status)=>{
        if(status){
            cb(null, status)
        }
        cb("ERROR-26")
    })
}
```

Here argument1 will be **'value1'**.

Final code should look something like

```
async.waterfall([
    function check_network(cb) {
        // if error
        cb("ERROR-25") // Handled at the end
        // else
        cb(null, "value1") // Will go to next funtion of waterfall
    },    
    function process_pay(arg1, cb){    
        somePromise().then((status)=>{
            if(status){
                cb(null, status)  // cb will work here
            }
            cb("ERROR-26")  // Error Handled at the end
        })
    },
    function print(arg1, cb){
        //some code
    } 
], function(error, result){
    // Handle Error here
})
```

For more info about async waterfall go to this [link](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html)